# Calling hashCode() from equals()

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have defined `hashCode()` for my class, with a lengthy list of class attributes.

Per the contract, I also need to implement equals(), but is it possible to implement it simply by comparing `hashCode()` inside, to avoid all the extra code? Are there any dangers of doing so?

e.g.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() 
{
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
        .append(field1)
        .append(field2)
    // etc.
    // ...
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    // Quick special cases
    if (that == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this == that) {
        return true;
    }
    // Now consider all main cases via hashCode()
    return (this.hashCode() == that.hashCode());
}
```

Comment: What happens when you have a hash code collision?

Comment: Unless you have a bijective hashcode function (that is unlikely) it's not a good way to implements equals. As @resueman said, if you have collisions you'll end up with two different objects being equals because they have the same hashcode value. Also your equals method does not check that the instances you are comparing have the same type, you could compare your instance with a String that have the same hashcode  value and it would return true. Definitely not what you're looking for I guess...

Comment: if two objects are equal according to the equals() method, they must have the same hashCode() value, but the the reverse is not generally true. So it is not recommended to implement equals() by comparing the hashcode()

Comment: It's worth noting that, even in situations where this is a valid approach, your implementation will fail, since it doesn't check that the objects are the same type.

Comment: You should take a look about ["AutoValue"](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14u_h-lMn7f1rXE1nDiLX0azS3IkgjGl5uxp5jGJ75RE/edit?pli=1#slide=id.g2a5e9c4a8_027). This generates `#equals()`, `#hashCode()` and `#toString()` for you, so you don't have to care about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't do that.

The contract for `hashCode()` says that two objects that are equal must have the same hashcode. It doesn't guarantee anything for objects that are not equal. What this means is that you could have two objects that are completely different but, by chance, happen to have the same hashcode, thus breaking your `equals()`.

It is not hard to get hashcode collisions between strings. Consider the core loop from the JDK 8 [`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    h = 31 * h + val[i];
}
```

Where the initial value for `h` is `0` and `val[i]` is the numerical value for the character in the *ith* position in the given string. If we take, for example, a string of length 3, this loop can be written as:

```
h = 31 * (31 * val[0] + val[1]) + val[2];
```

If we choose an arbitrary string, such as `"abZ"`, we have:

```
h("abZ") = 31 * (31 * 'a' + 'b') + 'Z'
h("abZ") = 31 * (31 * 97 + 98) + 90
h("abZ") = 96345
```

Then we can subtract `1` from `val[1]` while adding `31` to `val[2]`, which gives us the string `"aay"`:

```
h("aay") = 31 * (31 * 'a' + 'a') + 'y'
h("aay") = 31 * (31 * 97 + 97) + 121
h("aay") = 96345
```

Resulting in a collision: `h("abZ") == h("aay") == 96345`.

Also, note that your `equals()` implementation does not check if you are comparing objects of the same type. So, supposing you had `this.hashCode() == 96345`, the following statement would return `true`:

```
yourObject.equals(Integer.valueOf(96345))
```

Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, but in which case would a difference happen? If all my fields are Strings, would I be technically safe? (But I understand I shouldn't do it in general)

Comment: @dystroy Fair assumption since the OP is using `HashCodeBuilder` to build a hashcode which points to the commons class that does not enforce bijectivity of the hash function.

Comment: @geneb. No, strings are prone to lots of hash collisions.

Comment: If there are more than 2^32 possible values for your object, there are necessarily going to be hash collisions.  There are more than 2^32 possible strings.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to ask why a hashCode() is needed at all if it doesn't guarantee distinction, but I see now that it's used for quick contains() lookups in Collections and only then, if multiple objects are found, equals() is used to distinguish.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely **not** safe to just compare the `hashCode()` of your objects.

Your objects can have more different states than hash codes: Hash code is an `int`, that means it is limited to 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 possible values, but your object will probably have more than one single `int` field.

So it is proven, that there might be two different objects (according to equals) that have the same hash code.

But of course, you can first compare the hash codes for performance reasons (if hash code computation is faster than field comparison): If the hash codes are not equal, the objects are unequal too, so you can safely return `false` immediately!